# Echoing through PHP an HTML image path which is dynamic

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo a dynamic image path in PHP. I have this code that works

```
 <?php
 //this code works
 $image = '<img src="img/newlogo.jpg">';
 echo($image);
?>
//gives me an image
```

And this code that doesn't

```
 <?php
 //this code doesn't
 $lineofstring='newlogo.jpg';

 $image = '<img src="img/$lineofstring">';
 echo($image);
?>
```

$lineofsting is actually going to be an image path which is stored in a mysql database where one row is filled with, for example: pictureabc.jpg, second row is picturexyz.jpg etc.

I am trying to pass on the searched imagepath name onto $lineofstring, which is then echo'd but no picture comes out. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To interpolate variables in PHP, you need to use double quote marks `"`, e.g.

```
$image = "<img src=\"img/$lineofstring\">";
```

In this case, you need to escape the inner `"`.

You can also concatenate strings with `.`:

```
$image = '<img src="img/' . $lineofstring . '">';
```

if it's easier.

Comment: You can use single quotes in the echoed HTML to avoid the need to escape.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$lineofstring` variable is in a string using single quotes. Single quotes tell PHP to use the string literally so your variable is not being recognized as a variable. Change it to double quotes or use concatenation to accomplish your goals.

```
$image = "<img src=\"img/$lineofstring\">";
```

Or:

```
$image = '"<img src="img'.$lineofstring.'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$profilepicture="images/profiles/".$myid.".gif";
$noprofilepicture="images/profiles/no_avatar.gif";

echo "<IMG SRC='";
if (file_exists($profilepicture)) {
echo "".$profilepicture."";
} else {
echo "".$noprofilepicture."";
}
echo "'>";
```